# Difference in days between request status

Tags: sql, sql-server

This `SELECT` in the table shows the Status and the date and time the sample proposal entered. Basically I need to generate the LIFETIME of the proposal in each status.

```
SELECT  
    [PropostaID],
    [Status],
    [Descricao_Status],
    [Data_Hora_Criacao]
FROM 
    [DS_Market_FATO_Status_Proposta_Atual]
WHERE 
    PropostaID = 5437
ORDER BY 
    Data_Hora_Criacao ASC
```

Output:

```
PropostaID    Status   Descricao_Status              Data_Hora_Criacao
----------------------------------------------------------------------
5437            30     Análise de crédito enviada    2022-07-13 19:10:37.030
5437             1     Crédito aprovado              2022-07-13 19:50:56.470
5437             5     Documentação enviada          2022-07-14 17:24:43.570
5437             9     Documentação aprovada         2022-07-15 19:30:58.680
5437            28     Crédito liberado              2022-07-15 19:36:41.490
```

This is my SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    A.PropostaID,
    A.Status,
    A.Descricao_Status,
    A.Data_Hora_Criacao [Entrada],
    B.Data_Hora_Criacao [Saida],
    CASE 
        WHEN A.Data_Hora_Criacao IS NULL
            THEN 0
            ELSE DATEDIFF(DAY, A.Data_Hora_Criacao, B.Data_Hora_Criacao) 
    END AS timedifference
FROM 
    [DS_Market_FATO_Status_Proposta_Atual] A
JOIN 
    [DS_Market_FATO_Status_Proposta_Atual] B ON B.PropostaID = (SELECT  MIN(B2.PropostaID) 
                                                                FROM [DS_Market_FATO_Status_Proposta_Atual] B2 
                                                                WHERE B2.PropostaID > A.PropostaID 
                                                                  AND B2.Data_Hora_Criacao < A.Data_Hora_Criacao)
WHERE 
    A.Data_Hora_Criacao < B.Data_Hora_Criacao 
    AND A.PropostaID = 5437
ORDER BY 
    A.PropostaID,A.Data_Hora_Criacao, B.Data_Hora_Criacao ASC
```

It is producing the result below:

```
PropostaID  Status  Descricao_Status           Entrada                 Saida        timedifference
5437           1         Crédito aprovado     2022-07-13 19:50   2022-07-13 20:03               0
5437           1         Crédito aprovado     2022-07-13 19:50   2022-07-18 19:13               5
5437           5    Documentação enviada      2022-07-14 17:24   2022-07-18 19:13               4
5437           9    Documentação aprovada     2022-07-15 19:30   2022-07-18 19:13               3
5437           28    Crédito liberado         2022-07-15 19:36   2022-07-18 19:13               3
```

The result is missing a status and another is duplicated. Can someone help?

Comment: Are you looking for something like `DATEDIFF(MAX(date), IFNULL(MIN(date),'1970-01-01'))` or something?

Comment: I'm unclear on the Lifetime you are measuring?   Are you looking for the time between each different ```Status``` for the same ```PropostaID``` value or is the next ```PropostaID``` value relevant for this one?    With only a single ```PropostaID``` value in your sample data the join criteria ```WHERE B2.PropostaID > A.PropostaID``` removes all rows from the return set.

Comment: @MartinCairney I´m looking for the time between each different "Status" for the same "PropostaID" value                                                                                                                                   In the example, I need the output SQL shows5 rows for each different status of the same ProposalID:5437 and the lifetime ("timedifference") of each status.

Answer (score 0):

For something like this the [LAG](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-window-functions/sql-server-lag-function/) and [LEAD](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-window-functions/sql-server-lead-function/) window functions are very useful instead of using a self-join. Not only do you prevent the possibility of a cartesian-join (i.e. the row duplication which you are experiencing), but you have more options in how to interact with the data across rows.

Below is an example of how you could solve your problem using LAG:

```
WITH DS_Market_FATO_Status_Proposta_Atual_Deduplicate AS
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        PropostaID,
        Status,
        Descricao_Status,
        Data_Hora_Criacao
    FROM
        DS_Market_FATO_Status_Proposta_Atual
    WHERE
        PropostaID = 5437
    )

SELECT
    PropostaID,
    Status,
    Descricao_Status,
    Data_Hora_Criacao AS [Entrada],
    LAG(Data_Hora_Criacao, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY PropostaID ORDER BY Data_Hora_Criacao ASC) AS [Saida],
    DATEDIFF(SECOND, Data_Hora_Criacao, LAG(Data_Hora_Criacao, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY PropostaID ORDER BY Data_Hora_Criacao ASC)) AS Time_Difference
FROM
    DS_Market_FATO_Status_Proposta_Atual_Deduplicate ;
```

With this you end up with the following output:

| PropostaID | Status | Descricao_Status | Entrada | Saida | Time_Difference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5437 | 30 | Análise de crédito enviada | 2022-07-13 19:10:37.030 | null | null |
| 5437 | 1 | rédito aprovado | 2022-07-13 19:50:56.470 | 2022-07-13 19:10:37.030 | 2419 |
| 5437 | 5 | ocumentação enviada | 2022-07-14 17:24:43.570 | 2022-07-13 19:50:56.470 | 77627 |
| 5437 | 9 | ocumentação aprovada | 2022-07-15 19:30:58.680 | 2022-07-14 17:24:43.570 | 93975 |
| 5437 | 28 | Crédito liberado | 2022-07-15 19:36:41.490 | 2022-07-15 19:30:58.680 | 343 |

You can re-create all results from above in [SQL Lite Online](https://sqliteonline.com/). The only difference is you will need to replace the DATEDIFF function with the SQLite equivalent:
`ROUND((JULIANDAY(Data_Hora_Criacao) - JULIANDAY(LAG(Data_Hora_Criacao, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY PropostaID ORDER BY Data_Hora_Criacao ASC))) * 86400) AS Time_Difference`

Code for table creation in SQLite:

```
CREATE TABLE DS_Market_FATO_Status_Proposta_Atual
    (
    PropostaID int,
    Status INT,
    Descricao_Status nvarchar(100),
    Data_Hora_Criacao DATETIME2(0)
    ) ;

INSERT INTO
    DS_Market_FATO_Status_Proposta_Atual
VALUES
    (5437, 30, 'Análise de crédito enviada', '2022-07-13 19:10:37.030'),
    (5437,  1, 'Crédito aprovado', '2022-07-13 19:50:56.470'),
    (5437,  5, 'Documentação enviada', '2022-07-14 17:24:43.570'),
    (5437,  9, 'Documentação aprovada', '2022-07-15 19:30:58.680'),
    (5437, 28, 'Crédito liberado', '2022-07-15 19:36:41.490') ;
```

Hope this helps!